# Automatic post comments on Telegram

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I searched a lot but I didn't found what I'm looking for, Is that possible to make Telegram Bot that can detect some words in posts and attach comment if it's match the desired words???
If yes, plz provide some resources

Answer (score -2):

Take a look here:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples

For example, if you are using Java, you may use the following (through Maven):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you need to implement the specific APIs of that library, and deploy it to a real server (such that you app will be "alive").